# $modal is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$modal){
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = function(){
            $modal.open({
            template: '<h1>{{firstName}}</h1>',
            size: 'sm',
            backdrop: 'static'
        })}
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script><div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="submit" ng-click="lastName()"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName}}

</div>
```

I want to get the value of firstname in the modalpopup, the popup template should inherit the controller property and display the value right, it's not working. Can you please help?

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if it helped you solve your issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `$scope` to the modal instance like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$modal){
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = function(){
            $modal.open({
            scope: $scope,
            template: '<h1>{{firstName}}</h1>',
            size: 'sm',
            backdrop: 'static'
        })}
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script><div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="submit" ng-click="lastName()"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('testingCtrl',function($scope,param){
 //here you can able to access parent scope also
 $scope.firstName=param.data;
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$modal){
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = function(){
            $modal.open({
            template: '<h1>Name :{{firstName}}</h1>',
            size: 'sm',
            controller:'testingCtrl',
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
             param: function () {
                 return {
                  'data':$scope.firstName, 
                     'parentScope':$scope
                 };
             }
         } 
        })}
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script><div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="submit" ng-click="lastName()"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName}}

</div>
```